# Database Design with UML or Java

Tags: java, uml

What is the starting point in designing a database? UML or Java?
Eg: If u are using both java and UML for designing a database, how do you beging?

First with UML design and then Java script? Or the other way?

Comment: 1) Java **is not** JavaScript. 2) Java is a programming language, not a modelling language. 3) You need an [Entity Relationship model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). 4) UML doesn't provide an Entity Relationship diagram even if UML tools do. 5) Stating that the database design is the first step when building software is highly debatable, so there's no right answer to decide if the db must be designed before designing your domain entities using a [Domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) and move from one to the other.

Comment: If I were you, I would start by making a raw model using a piece of paper and a pencil **before** using any tool. With this, you will earn more experience on designing than any tool you could use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with [Entity-Relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) diagram.

> An ER model is an abstract way of describing a database. In the case
>   of a relational database, which stores data in tables, some of the
>   data in these tables point to data in other tables.For instance, your entry in the database could point to several entries for each of the phone numbers that are yours. The ER model would say that you are an entity, and each phone number is an entity, and the relationship between you and the phone numbers is 'has a phone number'. Diagrams created to design these entities and relationships are called entity–relationship diagrams or ER diagrams.

[Microsoft Visio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/hh973399.aspx) is one of the commonly used tool to do that.

Comment: Where did you get that Microsoft Visio is commonly used for this? I **never** used it for this purpose for not being so user friendly. I prefer tools like [ERwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_ERwin_Data_Modeler) or [MySQL Workbench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench).

Answer (score 2):

The starting point is the Diagram you will make to describe the relationships between the tables.

In your project you will have to have two different diagrams, one for the Java classes and another one for the database tables.

**EDIT**

I would recommend you to take a look at this link [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch), to make sure you will not confuse both schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely **not** the otherway... First design then validate the design then comes JAVA.

So use the Data Modeling (using ER diagrams) and then (if applicable) Object Modeling. As mentioned above Visio is a good tool, also you can use a pen-paper designs.

And when you talk about Data Design, ORM is very important to keep in mind.

Comment: *when you talk about Data Design, ORM is very important to keep in mind* the usage of an ORM depends on standards and other design restrictions, an ORM is not the panacea for DAO layer.